# How to Scroll to Top When drag an Element

Tags: jquery-ui

I have used JQuery UI to Drag my elements, I have some boxes (optin, product, uptell e.t.c) to drag on to the right area the box expands and show some input and labels as shown in the attached image.

[image]

I have given 600px height to the right side and made it auto scroll so that adding more elements will be shown at the same place.

But if one drags the element beneath the 600px the page scrolls down and on leaving the element it doesn't add into the place which is perfect, but it doesn't scroll back to top completely as shown in the below image. [image]

It should scrolls back to the top, for now I scroll it back to the top with the help of dragging element. (grab again one of the element and drag it to the top which scrolls back to the top).

Here is the my code.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
       
        $(".right-content").droppable({
            cursor: 'grab',
            accept: '#optin',
            stack: '.ui-draggable',
             drop: function (event, ui) {
               $('#dropArea').append("<div class='optin movable'><div class='col-sm-6 col-lg-4 module'><div class='module-box bg-info'><h2>Optin</h2><div class='form-horizontal'><div class='form-group'><label class='control-label col-xs-7' for='conversionrate'>Conversion Rate</label><div class='col-xs-5'><input name='ConverstionRate' class='form-control text-box single-line calculationText' id='ConversionRate' type='text' value='' data-val-required='The ConverstionRate field is required.' data-val-number='The field ConverstionRate must be a number.' data-val='true'></div></div><h4>Number Of Leads : <span id='numberOfLeads'></span></h4><h4>Cost Per Lead : <span id='costPerLead'></span></h4><h4>Advertising Cost : <span id='costOfAdvertising'></span></h4><h4>Net Profits : <span class='label' id='netProfit'></span></h4><h4>Net Profit Year 1 : <span class='label' id='year1'></span></h4><h4>Net Profit Year 2 : <span class='label' id='year2'></span></h4></div></div></div></div>");
             }
        });
        
        $('#optin').draggable({helper:'clone', cursor:'move', stack:'.ui-draggable' });
});
```

```css
    .body-content,.container-fluid, .body-content > .row {
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
    }

    .margin-padding {
       margin: 80px 0 0 0;
    }

    body {
       padding-top: 50px;
       padding-bottom: 20px;
       overflow: hidden;
    }

    .module-box {
       height: 620px;
       padding: 20px;
       margin-top: 10px;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
     }

    .right-content {
       height: 520px;
       overflow-y: auto;
    }

    #draggableArea {
       padding: 25px 20px 50px 20px;
    }

    #dropArea {
       padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
       margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    .margin-for-upersection {
       margin-top: 30px;
       margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<head>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
       <div class="row margin-padding">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <ul id="draggableArea" class="list-unstyled">
              <li id="optin">
              <div id="optinDragDiv" class="bg-info" style="height:80px;">
        <h4 style="color:#333; text-align:center; padding:30px 20px;">Optin</h4>            
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
        <div id="clicks" class="row margin-for-upersection">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                       <label for="TargetClicks">Targeted Clicks</label>
                       <input name="TargetedClicks" placeholder="Targeted CLicks" class="calculationText form-control text-box single-line" id="TargetedClicks" type="text" value="" >
                         
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <label for="cost">Cost Per Click</label>
                        <input name="CostPerClick" placeholder="Cost Per Click" class="calculationText form-control text-box single-line" id="CostPerClick" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <div id="dropArea" class="right-content row">
          <div class="row">
            </div>


          </div>

        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please share your code or at least a Fiddle. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty I have shown the code and link to JS fiddle